# how to annotate a class declaration defined in one file within another?

Tags: typescript

In one file `content.ts`, I have a class definition and a method:

```js
class Content{
  constructor(){
    this.hello = 'hello';
    this.world = 'word';
  }
}

function print_content(input: Content){
  console.log(input.hello, input.world);
}

export default {Content};
```

In another file: `main.ts`, I want to create additional print function:

```js
import content from `./content`

function print_content1(input: content.Content){
  console.log(input.hello, input.world);
}

function print_content2(input: typeof content.Content){
  console.log(input.hello, input.world);
}
```

However, neither functions in `main.ts` work. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Except for the missing class declarations should work: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/FAOwhgtgpgzgDmAxlABIg9iALlbKDewKxKUAHnOgE5ZoA2YMMKAwpjnoSdygBZR066AFwoYWKgEsQAcwDcRHsQDu1OgBNR4qbIVLiGENoCuiLNQAUASgKL9JLL0kwAdP0HoUAXhQByd0K+evYOTq6qVBrefhHqQXY8AL4JycnAAGbGIGaSmChwOlgA+oYcWBbScMZYoqW4WC5s2PU2XCSGMOh0UC5CMhUgVQ0B6AA0KJXVLhEaVgppwBlZOXkF0sV12ACMA0O17PWNB9itCR1dPX27UyPjkw0z6nPAiUA

Comment: okay, it works when I put in the export keyword. what does this do in terms of packaging?. I'll be happy to accept an answer.